# How to set up MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, minecraft, bukkit

I'm running a VPS to host a Minecraft (video game) server.

For some of the data that the server collects from players, it is more efficient sometimes for it to store user information in a database in order to take a load off of the server.

I have successfully created a MySQL database called "minecraft" in Ubuntu 13.04 terminal.
[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mP3b.png) of everything I typed to create the database.

A Minecraft Bukkit server plugin that I am using to test the connection,  LogBlock, cannot connect to the server. I have put in the details as follows:

```
mysql:
user: root
port: 3306
password: -mypassword-
host: localhost
database: minecraft
```

The Minecraft server simply returns that there is no database connected.

The MySQL server does not seem to be active at all. I have it running, but cannot connect to it through SQuirreL SQL either. Can anyone give me some advice on how I can actually test the database or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the server remotely via command line?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: `mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb`, as seen on the [_connecting_](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html) documentation page.

Comment: I... think it worked. The Linux terminal changed to mysql> when I typed it.

Comment: Is port 3306 forwarded?

Comment: I would assume that all ports are forwarded.
How would I forward a port on a VPS that I'm renting from someone else?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `127.0.0.1` or your IP address for the VPS and try again.

Make sure the database can actually establish a connection through the port, just do a quick check here to see if the port is open: **http://ping.eu/port-chk/**

To check your mysql status on Ubuntu:

```
status mysql
```

or this way

```
pgrep -l mysqld
```

Hopefully this should help, if you still can't get anywhere then let me know Josias and I can provide further assistance

Comment: `status` is not installed by default on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a MySQL server for the first time can be tricky. But once you get the hang of things it starts to get real easy. Heres a great place to get started with MySQL on you're ubuntu server: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html